# Placing div2 when the content is bigger than the size of div1

Tags: css, html, height, overflow

I try to render a page on mobile with responsive css.
I can't change the html, and i try to resolve my problem only with css.

Imagine that i have a div like that :

```
#example {
   width : 25px;
   height : 25px;
}
```

Inside this div, i have an 1024*768 image.
So the content is bigger than the contener (and i will show all the content)
My problem is that the following content will be placed at 25px of the top, not below the image.

EDIT : a new jsfiddle, more precise : http://jsfiddle.net/eABu5/12/

Do you have any idea ?
Many thanks

Comment: Why are the dimensions of you `#example` div set to 25x25 when your image has larger dimensions?

Comment: The div never change dimension. The image is here fot the demo, but in my case it's text. Look a the new jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eABu5/11/

Comment: Concerning the `#under` caption/label element, where do you want it positioned, below the bottom edge of the image, or below the bottom edge of `#example` such that the overflowing image is painted over the text so that the caption/label is not visible?

Comment: Look at the most recent Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eABu5/12/ . The #under must but just below the text in Lorem Ipsum , regardless the size of the text. Thanks Marc !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ovaxoLa/6/edit)

CSS

```
#example {
   width : 250px;
   height : 250px;
   background-color : #123456;
}

#pic {
   margin-top: 250px;
   float: left;    
}


#under {
   margin-top: 10px; 
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your solution works perfectly on your demo and in jsfiddle... but not in my site :/ I will continue my investigation :)

Comment: I have reproduce more precisely what's doesn't work in my precise case. The content has a position : relative, and a top which is the same size of the div. look the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/eABu5/11/

Comment: Many Thanks @aldanux ! But it's not exactly ok. For a better understanding, I have replace the image by a text. The text can have different height. If the text is longer than 250px, it's ok. But when is under 250px, there is a margin between the text, and the line. Look at my updated Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eABu5/12/ And again : THANKS, it really nice of you !

Comment: @Thomas :) Ok ... I think I have now definitely the solution ... I've updated my answer. You can vary the text (#pic) and the text (#under) is always below with a margin (if you want). Try it out and tell me if solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. Your solution really helped me gain a lot of time and headache. I am really grateful to you. THANKS from paris :)

Comment: You're welcome! Took a little longer but the main thing is... it is now solved! I'm glad that it helped you so ... Greetings from Málaga :)

Comment: Oups... Your solution only work on chrome... :( I've just try on safari desktop/mobile and on chrome mobile, and it doesnt work... Houson, we have a problem... I'm so sad :(

Comment: This is pretty good and will probably work provided that there are no other inline-blocks or floated elements right before `#example`.  However, you could work around that by adding a pseudo element right before `#example` to start a new block or clear the floats.

Comment: :) Try it out now! I tested in Chrome, FF and Safari! And works..really now! :D

Comment: Thanks, thanks, and thanks. Thank you for your patience and your help. You really simplified the life of someone today :)